# Conductor VAD for OpenLink Virtuoso 6.1.6?

Tags: virtuoso

I have a Linux system with Virtuoso 6.1.6, but it does not have the Conductor VAD. And under the official links from openlinksw, I can only download it for 7.1.

When I try the 7.1 it says "Please update server version"

Where can I get the Conductor VAD for 6.1.6?

Answer (score 0):

We ([OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/) is my employer) always recommend updating to the latest version (currently 7.2), but given that you're staying with Virtuoso 6 for whatever reason -- the download page does have and has had [VADs for Release 6.4](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/download/#Release64VADPackages).  I'm not sure why you didn't find them...

Also... Faster Virtuoso-specific answers often come through the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users), our [public Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or our [confidential Case System](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).